# Resizeable scrollable TableLayoutPanel in Winforms

Tags: winforms, autoscroll

I have a UserControl that I want to be scrollable if necessary.

The control is also docked in the form that it's contained in.

Everything in the UserControl is inside a TableLayoutPanel that has AutoScroll=True.

My problem is that it looks like the scrollbar is added before the control is resized, so that the control ends up with the scrollbar even though it's not really needed after the control has been resized.

Is there a way to force the scrollbar to be added after the control is resized so that it's added only if it's still needed after the resize?

Comment: How the Scrollbars behave depends on how the TLP is configured and also how the Controls it contains are configured (e.g., you may have quite different behavior when the child Controls are docked in the TLP's cells and their `MinimumSize` is set) -- Possibly, post the Designer of your UC and the code that adds it to a Form, if this is done at run-time, how the UC is docked, etc.. In any case, when you add a TLP to a Form, make sure you call `SuspendLayout()`, then `ResumeLayout()` (passing `true` or `false`, depending on the configuration) or `PerformLayout()`

Comment: I figured out what I had to do to make it work the way I wanted it to, but thanks for responding.  I appreciate it.